# mvn test - override values in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, application.properties

I have these properties in my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhsost:5432/myDatabase
spring.datasource.username=myUsername
```

I would like to run `mvn test` with other values than the above, for example:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://my.test.server.com:5432/myDatabase
spring.datasource.username=anotherUsername
```

I tried the following

```
mvn test -Drun.arguments='--spring.datasource.jdbc:postgresql://my.test.server.com:5432/myDatabase --spring.datasource.username=anotherUsername'
```

and without `spring` prefix:

```
mvn test -Drun.arguments='--datasource.jdbc:postgresql://my.test.server.com:5432/myDatabase --datasource.username=anotherUsername'
```

But this does not seem to work. How can I override the values in the `application.properties` in context of running `mvn test`?

Comment: You need to create `profiles`. For example: `application-local.properties`, `application-dev.properties`, `application-prod.properties`

Comment: why you don't create specific `application.properties` file in your `test/resources` directory ?

Comment: @hamidghasemi because I run `mvn test` in different pipelines where the values are all different (dev pipeline is different to master pipeline)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html
and read that too, maybe it will be useful

Comment: `--spring.datasource.jdbc:` is obviously not a correct property --`spring.datasource.url=<your-url-here>` is. Basically you are supplying the wrong parameters and thus there is nothing to override. However I would strongly suggest the use of profiles and the support that Spring Boot has for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <spring.datasource.jdbc>value</spring.datasource.jdbc>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

But more often we do this by placing a test version of `application.properties` into the `src/test/resources`. During testing, that file will have greater priority.

Answer (score 4):

When overriding parameters in the command line, use a comma as separator, not a space:

```
mvn test -Drun.arguments='--spring.datasource.url=...,--spring.datasource.username=...'
```

This should work too:

```
mvn test -Dspring.datasource.url=... -Dspring.datasource.username=...
```

### Edit from april 2021

The syntax above was valid for Spring Boot 1.X.
With Spring Boot 2.0/2.1, use:

```
mvn test -Dspring-boot.run.arguments='--spring.datasource.url=...,--spring.datasource.username=...'
```

And with Spring Boot 2.2, the syntax was changed again (use a whitespace as separator):

```
mvn test -Dspring-boot.run.arguments='--spring.datasource.url=... --spring.datasource.username=...'
```

Other answers and comments mention using profiles and put a custom `application.properties` in `/src/test/resources`, which is not a viable solution for you since you use different pipelines, but if I remember correctly, you can even use `application-{profile}.properties` in `/src/test/resources`. This way you should be able to maintain one test profile per pipeline, where you put your custom parameters, and then test your pipeline with:

```
mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another `application-dev.properties` file and paste:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://my.test.server.com:5432/myDatabase
spring.datasource.username=anotherUsername
```

Then run with the option `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` in your `mvn` command.

- E.g.: `mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

You can add as many profiles as needed.

- syntax: `application-<profile name>.properties`

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** (*preferred as is Maven structure-specific*)

Create an `application.properties` under the `test/resources` to be picked up for your testing purposes

**Option 2** (*Spring Test fine-tuning a particular Test class alone*)

Override your properties directly on the Test class by inlining the ones you want by using [@TestPropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testpropertysource)

**Option 3** (*Spring Boot - multiple properties files or a single YAML file*)

Group the props under a Spring Profile ([Example here](http://*Spring%20Boot%20-%20multiple%20properties%20files%20or%20a%20single%20YAML%20file*)) and invoke it directly from maven:  `mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active="myOtherSpringProfile"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see many people using the environment variable option. If you set an environment variable for corresponding properties, then the value in the environment variable will be used. e.g.

Environment variables:
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL="jdbc:postgresql://my.test.server.com:5432/myDatabase"
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=anotherUsername

Inside the properties file:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhsost:5432/myDatabase
spring.datasource.username=myUsername

The application will use the values in the environment variables. For this to work you'll need to follow the naming convention. Use uppercase and replace "." with "_".